# Errno 22 invalid mode ('rb') or filename - django custom file storage

Tags: python, django, file-io, amazon-s3

I have overwritten the default file storage in django to save the model image fields in amazon s3.

only the `open` method is not working as expected, I am getting:

```
[Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: http://image.buzzhearts.com/media/2015/11/12/11/99f0301c46d7945c91b16b0c2d61ab13.jpg
```

the file is already in s3: http://image.buzzhearts.com/media/2015/11/12/11/99f0301c46d7945c91b16b0c2d61ab13.jpg

code:

```
class CS3Storage(FileSystemStorage):
    def open(self, name, mode='rb'):
        return File(open(self.path(name), mode)) # <-- problem

    def path(self, name):
        # returns http://image.buzzhearts.com/media/2015/11/12/11/99f0301c46d7945c91b16b0c2d61ab13.jpg
        return 'http://image.buzzhearts.com/%s' % name
```

what am I missing? I think, I have to first get the image file from s3 with e.g. `requests` and then open right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`open()` takes a filename, it does not support urls.

If you want to fetch the url, you need to use a library like `requests`. Since the file is on S3, you could use a tool like boto.

Instead of writing your own file storage, you might find it easier to use [django-storages-redux](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-storages-redux).

Comment: thanks, yeah I know, but my bucket is in frankfurt and they dont support sigv2. I had lots of headaches from django-storages and django-storages-redux. so i decided to use my own storage.

Comment: you mean, I can use boto in open() method of storage?

Comment: Your last question was about `django-storages`, so I wanted to make sure you knew about `django-storages-redux`

Comment: No, I mean you can use boto to fetch a file from a bucket, *instead* of `open()`, not *in* `open()`.